# Issue in executing trades intraday with pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I have the following pinescript. I want the script to be a intraday script. Based on some condition, it should short the stocks at a limit order. If the order is fulfilled then if either stoploss or target is not hit then square-off towards the end of trading session in India.

```
strategy('Mean Reversion Shivam', overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, currency='USD', default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
  default_qty_value=100, commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order, commission_value=20)

//  === Max Intraday Orders ===
strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders(count=1)  


// ===  STRATEGY INPUTS ===

// Backtest Date
start = input.time(defval = timestamp("01 Jan 2019 06:00 +0000"), title = "Backtest Start Date", group = "backtest window")
end = input.time(defval = timestamp("01 Dec 2021 00:00 +0000"), title = "Backtest End Date", group = "backtest window")
posExitSession = input.session(title="Position exit session", defval="1455-1530", confirm=true)
movingAverage = input.int(title="Moving average period", defval=200, minval=1,maxval=200, step=5)
shortProfitPerc = input.float(title="Short Profit (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.5, defval=3) / 100
shortStopLossPerc = input.float(title="Short Stop Loss (%)", minval=0.0, step=0.5, defval=3) / 100
 


// ==== FUNCTIONS ====
// A function to check whether the bar or period is in intraday session
barInSession(session) => time(timeframe.period, session) !=na


// ==== SHORT CONDITION ===
shortCondition = close[1]> ta.sma(close,movingAverage)
strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, qty=1, limit= 1.01*close, when=shortCondition and time > start and time < end)
shortProfitExitPrice=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)
shortLossExitPrice=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + shortStopLossPerc)


// === EXIT MAX PROFIT === 
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="short", limit=shortProfitExitPrice, stop=shortLossExitPrice)

// ==== Daily Square Off ===
bool intradayExitDuration = barInSession(posExitSession)
squareOff = intradayExitDuration and hour == 15
strategy.close_all(when = squareOff, comment = "Square-off")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know what issue are you facing. I will give a try to answer based on the title of this question.

If you want to square off at the last bar of the session then you can also use below code.

```
if session.islastbar_regular
    strategy.close_all(immediately = true)
```

session.islastbar_regular will find the last bar in the regular session of the security you are running backtest on. using `immediately = true` will ensure that the all pending orders are closed immediately regardless of what order processing instructions you are using in your strategy input.